# Detect if vertical UIBezierpath contains touchPoint and return the middle Point of the path relate to touchPoint

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I have a straight UIBezierpath that can be stretched and rotated to whatever angle:

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

When I touch at black arrow point, it should says `isContain = true` and return a `CGPoint` that close to `touchPoint` and must be in the middle of the `path` (blue arrow).

For example: Black arrow point is `(x:251,y:302)` but it should return `(x:250, y:300)`, which is in the middle of the `path`

This is what I tried but it only works with horizontal line

```
 func hasForHorizontalLine(pt point: CGPoint) -> Bool{
            
            let bezierRect = bounds
            let origin = bezierRect.origin
            let size = bezierRect.size

            if origin.x <= point.x , origin.x + size.width >= point.x, origin.y - lineWidth * 0.5 <= point.y , origin.y + lineWidth * 0.5 >= point.y{
                return true
            }
            else{
                return false
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the angle of the red line relative to the horizontal, or its equation?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I have the angle